# tree-search algorithm with n steps

Tags: combinatorics

I have no idea how to do this. There are $n!$ possible binary search trees. There is the simple tree that has root $n$ and just keep going left-down to $n-1$ then $n-2$ until $1$ which requires $n$ steps.

I am unsure why the question says 'at least' because I cant see a way to make a tree that gives more than n steps. There seems to only be one tree that gives n steps so the answer would be $1/n!$ but that just seems so simple. Please help.

TREE-SEARCH algorithm$(x,k)$:
searches for $k$ within the sub-tree rooted at $x$. If $x$=NIL, it means that the sub-tree is empty and $k$ cannot be found there.

1. If $x$=NIL, then return NOT-FOUND;
2. if $key[x]=k$, then return $x$ (success);
3. if $k<key[x]$, then TREE-SEARCH$(left[x],k])$;
4. if $k>key[x]$, then TREE-SEARCH$(right[x],k])$;

Comment: going from root(n-1) to n is 1 step. Then going from n to 1 would be n-1 steps. so in total there is 1+n-1=n steps right... or am I missing something.

Comment: when you make a binary search tree, you can choose how it is placed out. like in this example here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205939/all-possible-binary-search-trees

Comment: To make this Question answerable, I think you need to specify not only the TREE-SEARCH algorithm (and how the steps are counted), but the tree construction algorithm.  Saying "you can choose how it is placed out" merely suggests the location of $1$ could be anywhere in the tree and does not give a clear connection with the order of arrival that you highlight with the first sentence of your Question.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. the second tree I talked about in the question isn't obtainable by the standard routine which is what you were thinking and convincing me about earlier. I have edited the question. It seems to me that there is only one tree that would give n steps, giving the answer 1/n! but that seems too simple...

Comment: By "standard" you mean "the simple algorithm my textbook gave that no good software library would actually use," is that right? In real life, someone who bothers to build a binary search tree will very likely make _some_ attempt to balance it, so the answer to this question would be "zero". In other words, what hardmath said, although I think we can guess what kind of algorithm was intended.

Comment: are you serious or being sarcastic lol? it is zero? there is clearly one, don't know if there are any more

Comment: I would guess, as I think @DavidK does (and it is just a guess), that arriving keys are to be inserted to the left or right of the current node, according to whether they are less or more than the key stored there.  In this understanding of the problem, trees are not balanced but there will be more than one way that $1$ gets stored "in the last place you look".

Comment: Yeah there is more than one tree that would make you find 1 at the last place you look but it wouldn't be n steps. The only way it woild be n steps is the tree that I mentioned in the question which I think you agree with. But the thing that is confusing me the most is knowing how many possible trees you can make with these keys. I dont think it is simply n! Because in the link I gave in this page, there were 1,2,3 and it had 5 possible trees - not 3!=6...

Comment: @snowman I was being 100% serious. There are many algorithms for inserting nodes in binary search trees. Most of them have provisions to change the links between existing nodes so that it is literally impossible for all the nodes to be in one long chain no matter what order they arrive in. This is why the context of a question is important: in many cases we can't know what algorithms you're assuming unless you describe them in a reasonable amount of detail. (In this particular case, the fact that it is possible to have one long chain is a pretty good clue about your assumptions.)

Comment: It occurs to me that I'm very likely telling you things you were supposed to learn next week, and this exercise was supposed to help motivate the algorithms you'll discuss later.

Comment: yeah probably. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The only way that a tree will find 1 in at least n steps is if the keys arrive in order $n,n-1,...,2,1$.

Comment: And the number of ways that these keys can arrive is n! Right? So the answer is 1/n!?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: How would you explain that if it isnt in that order, then there wouldn't be n steps to reach 1?

Comment: @snowman I think your doubts about the $n!$ number of trees are good thinking. There are fewer than $n!$ possible trees in general. For example, if I guessed correctly what algorithm constructs your tree, the input 3,4,5,1,2 produces the same tree as 3,1,2,4,5 or 3,1,4,2,5.

Comment: I know, this question is sooo badly written